# WCF Service issue in IOS on MAC OS

Tags: ios, wcf, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a `WCF` service that returns `XML` string that I am consuming from `Xamarin.iOS` on `MAC OS` but it is throwing `NullReferenceException` When Method that return `XML` is called . I checked while debugging and found that `State` and `EndPoint` is not getting created when I creating proxy as it is stated in screen shot below . But it is working fine in `Android` on `Windows`

Comment: Could you share more information, like bits of code ?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089234/cant-access-webservice-using-xamarin-and-wcf and its answer ?